# gulp-sass new line for multi selector

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I want to build

```
.btn-default {
    color: #ccc;

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: #ddd;
    }
}
```

into

```
.btn-default {
    color: #ccc;
}

.btn-default:hover, 
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #ddd;
}
```

But instead, it compares into

```
.btn-default {
    color: #ccc;
}

.btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {
    color: #ddd;
}
```

On the other hand, it works fine without `&`, which build

```
a,
.btn {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

into

```
a,
.btn {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

So, how should I build `&` into multi-lines?

I use gulp-sass. Option is available [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options).

Comment: Even one selector with `&` and other without works. So looks like only when both the Sass compiler itself outputs it in one line

Answer (score 1):

Sass only provide 4 compile output style:
(https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outputstyle)

`:nested`
`:expanded`
`:compact`
`:compressed`

There's no way to get the result you want, but you can use something like : https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js to format it.